# sort key then by subkey—if subkey undef set to null string

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, perl-data-structures

```
my %data (
    KEY1 => {
        SUBKEY1 => "Canada",
        SUBKEY3 => "75.00",
        SUBKEY2 => "50.00",    
    },
    KEY3 => {
        SUBKEY2 => "150.00",
    },  
    KEY2 => { 
        SUBKEY3 => "200.00",
        SUBKEY1 => "Mexico",
 },
);
```

How do I print a list that is sorted by Keyname and for each keyname sorted by subkeyname?

Here is what I want to print:
(notice that if the subkey wasn't defined, a placeholder for the subkey with a null string is present)

```
KEY1: SUBKEY1 is "Canada"
KEY1: SUBKEY2 is "50.00"
KEY1: SUBKEY3 is "75.00"
KEY2: SUBKEY1 is ''
KEY2: SUBKEY2 is "150.00"
KEY2: SUBKEY3 is ''
KEY3: SUBKEY1 is "Mexico"
KEY3: SUBKEY2 is ''
KEY3: SUBKEY3 is "200.00"
```

Comment: Mexico is in `$data{KEY2}` but associated with `KEY3` in your expected output.

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = (
    KEY1 => {
        SUBKEY1 => "Canada",
        SUBKEY3 => "75.00",
        SUBKEY2 => "50.00",    
    },
    KEY3 => {
        SUBKEY2 => "150.00",
    },  
    KEY2 => { 
        SUBKEY3 => "200.00",
        SUBKEY1 => "Mexico",
 },
);

my %all_sub_keys;
for my $sub_hash (values %data){
    $all_sub_keys{$_} ++ for keys %$sub_hash;
}

my @all_sub_keys = sort keys %all_sub_keys;

for my $k ( sort keys %data ){
    for my $sk (@all_sub_keys){
        my $val = exists $data{$k}{$sk} ? $data{$k}{$sk} : '--';
        print join(' ', $k, $sk, $val), "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use 5.10.0;  # for // (aka defined-or)
use warnings;
use strict;

my %data = ...;

# get all subkeys used in %data
my @subkeys = keys %{
  { map { map +($_ => 1),
          keys %{ $data{$_} } }
    keys %data
  }
};

print map qq|$_->[0]: $_->[1] is "$_->[2]"\n|,
      sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0]
                     ||
             $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
      map { my $key = $_;
            map [ $key, $_, $data{$key}{$_} // "" ] =>
            @subkeys }
      keys %data;
```

Remember to read Schwartzian transforms from back-to-front. The first—closest to the end—`map` flattens or "denormalizes" `%data` into a list of records in some unspecified order. The nested `map` is necessary to reach the subkeys. To handle arbitrarily deep nesting, define `flatten` recursively.

We made an earlier pass to collect all the subkeys used, so if a particular subkey is not present, the value of `$data{$key}{$_}` is the undefined value. Using `//`, the defined-or operator new in version 5.10.0, specifies a default value of `""`.

With flattened records of the form

```
[ "KEY1", "SUBKEY3", "75.00" ],
[ "KEY1", "SUBKEY1", "Canada" ],
...
```

sorting is straightforward: compare the respective first elements (the keys) and if those are equal, fall back to the seconds (the subkeys).

Finally, the outermost `map` formats the now-sorted denormalized records for output, and the resulting list goes to the standard output by way of the `print` operator.

Output:

```
KEY1: SUBKEY1 is "Canada"
KEY1: SUBKEY2 is "50.00"
KEY1: SUBKEY3 is "75.00"
KEY2: SUBKEY1 is "Mexico"
KEY2: SUBKEY2 is ""
KEY2: SUBKEY3 is "200.00"
KEY3: SUBKEY1 is ""
KEY3: SUBKEY2 is "150.00"
KEY3: SUBKEY3 is ""
```

To group subkeys on the same line with the respective key of each, go with code such as

```
my @subkeys = sort keys %{ ... ;

foreach my $key (sort keys %data) {
  my @values;
  foreach my $subkey (@subkeys) {
    my $value = $data{$key}{$subkey} // "";
    push @values => qq|$subkey is "$value"|;
  }

  local $" = ", ";
  print "$key: @values\n";
}
```

You could write it in a functional style, but the result is a muddy mess:

```
print map { my $key = $_;
            "$key: " .
              join(", " =>
                map { my $value = $data{$key}{$_} // "";
                      qq|$_ is "$value"|
                    }
                @subkeys) .
            "\n"
          }
      sort keys %data;
```

Output:

```
KEY1: SUBKEY1 is "Canada", SUBKEY2 is "50.00", SUBKEY3 is "75.00"
KEY2: SUBKEY1 is "Mexico", SUBKEY2 is "", SUBKEY3 is "200.00"
KEY3: SUBKEY1 is "", SUBKEY2 is "150.00", SUBKEY3 is ""
```

Comment: Thanks, I had been researching that method but I just couldn't grasp the syntax until you posted this example...very nice!

Comment: what does this line do?
    map [ $key, $_, $data{$key}{$_} // "" ] =>

Comment: Thank you gbacon for the solution AND the wonderful explanation

I'm still a little perplexed, perhaps if you had the time, you could show how you would re-write to produce the following output:
    KEY1: SUBKEY1 is "Canada", SUBKEY2 is "50.00", SUBKEY3 is "75.00" NEWLINE
    KEY2: SUBKEY1 is "Mexico", SUBKEY2 is "", SUBKEY3 is "200.00" NEWLINE
    KEY3: SUBKEY1 is "", SUBKEY2 is "150.00", SUBKEY3 is "" NEWLINE

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the set of subkeys is known ahead of time.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %data = (
    KEY1 => {
        SUBKEY1 => "Canada",
        SUBKEY3 => "75.00",
        SUBKEY2 => "50.00",
    },
    KEY3 => {
        SUBKEY2 => "150.00",
    },
    KEY2 => {
        SUBKEY3 => "200.00",
        SUBKEY1 => "Mexico",
 },
);

my @subkeys = qw( SUBKEY1 SUBKEY2 SUBKEY3 );

for my $key ( sort keys %data ) {
    my %sub = map {
        my $v = $data{$key}{$_};
        $_ => defined($v) ? $v : '';
    } @subkeys;

    for my $subkey ( @subkeys ) {
        print "$key $subkey $sub{$subkey}\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
KEY1 SUBKEY1 Canada
KEY1 SUBKEY2 50.00
KEY1 SUBKEY3 75.00
KEY2 SUBKEY1 Mexico
KEY2 SUBKEY2
KEY2 SUBKEY3 200.00
KEY3 SUBKEY1
KEY3 SUBKEY2 150.00
KEY3 SUBKEY3
```